# Zend .htaccess redirect to main url

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect index.php to main url or also /index to main url. I'm using Zend Framework.
My current .htaccess

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index https://sim.ca/
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ – [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

I want to make some URL rewriting : if someone types `https://sim.ca/index.php` or `https://sim.ca/index` then it will be redirected to `https://sim.ca`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simplify your rules to this:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
#Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirect /index and /index.php to /
RewriteRule ^index(\.php)?$ / [R=301,L]

#Any custom rules should be above here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [NC,L]

#Rewrite all requests that reach this point to the router page
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your rule like this:

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^index(\.php)?/?$ https://sim.ca/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```